# How to detect scrollView scrolling direction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` inside that I have a `UITableView` The scroll view should scrol horizontally. And I have implemented `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` to do some tasks when the scroll view end its horizontal scrolling. But My problem is, this delegate is firing even when the `UITableView` vertical scrolling stopped too. So how can I detect just the `scrollview` horizontal scrolling within this delegate?

Please help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check these delegate methods

```
CGPoint _lastContentOffset;

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  _lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

  - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (_lastContentOffset.x < (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
      NSLog(@"Scrolled Right");
    }
    else if (_lastContentOffset.x > (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
      NSLog(@"Scrolled Left");
    }

    else if (_lastContentOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
      NSLog(@"Scrolled Down");
    }

    else if (_lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
      NSLog(@"Scrolled Up");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
  var _lastContentOffset: CGPoint!

  func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     _lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
  }

  func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if _lastContentOffset.x < scrollView.contentOffset.x {
      NSLog("Scrolled Right")
    }
    else if _lastContentOffset.x > scrollView.contentOffset.x {
      NSLog("Scrolled Left")
    }

    else if _lastContentOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
      NSLog("Scrolled Down")
    }

    else if _lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
      NSLog("Scrolled Up")
    }
}
```

Comment: It is always good to add some explanation to your code :)