# Reset current page number in label

Tags: ios, swift, label, uipagecontrol

I use **collectionView** (inside **tableView**) for horizontal scrolling image and **tableView** for vertical scroll info.

If i **scroll up** or **scroll down** i get **auto reset** my page number, what can be the reason? But if i continue scrolling image i get current page number.

My code for display current page number:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DetailTableViewCell2 {

        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)

        cell.currentPageNumber.text = "\(String(Int(pageNumber) + 1))/\(hallImages?.ImagesHalls.count ?? 0)"

    }

}
```

[image: currentPageNumber]

**EDIT:** cellForRowAt method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell2

    cell2.currentPageNumber.text = "1/\(hallImages?.ImagesHalls.count ?? 0)"

    cell2.descriptionLabel.text = hallImages?.hallDescription

    cell2.nameLabel.text = hallImages?.studioName

    cell2.addressLabel.text = hallImages?.studioAddress

    cell2.priceLabel.text = hallImages?.hallPrice

    cell2.metrs.text = hallImages?.hallMetrs

    cell2.logoLabel.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: (hallImages?.studioLogo)!))
    cell2.logoLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    cell2.logoLabel.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell2

}
```

Comment: show your `UITableView` `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: added in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a check of the scroll direction using the below code and add your code in appropriate condition

```
CGPoint _lastContentOffset;

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  _lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

  - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (_lastContentOffset.x < (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
      NSLog(@"Scrolled Right");
    }
    else if (_lastContentOffset.x > (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
      NSLog(@"Scrolled Left");
    }

    else if (_lastContentOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
      NSLog(@"Scrolled Down");
    }

    else if (_lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
      NSLog(@"Scrolled Up");
    }
}
```

Reference from my answer : [How to detect scrollView scrolling direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941092/how-to-detect-scrollview-scrolling-direction/32941222#32941222)

**Edited for Swift 3**

```
var _lastContentOffset = CGPoint.zero

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if lastContentOffset.x < Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
        print("Scrolled Right")
    }
    else if lastContentOffset.x > Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
        print("Scrolled Left")
    }
    else if lastContentOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        print("Scrolled Down")
    }
    else if lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        print("Scrolled Up")
    }

}
```

Comment: It's hard for me, because i know only Swift, not Obj-C :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply compare the instance of CollectionView with scrollView so that you can calculate the page number in case of tableViewScroll it ignores the calculation:

```
 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == collectionView {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DetailTableViewCell2 {
                let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
                cell.currentPageNumber.text = "\(String(Int(pageNumber) + 1))/\(hallImages?.ImagesHalls.count ?? 0)"
            }
        }
    }
```